# Get solution path in debug mode

Tags: .net

I'm writing a program that uses an xml file to import some control data. While writing this program this xml file with the control data changes a lot.

Right now I'm getting the xml file at startup time by figuring out in which directory my program runs in and looking for the file in that directory.
But this way I had to change the xml file in at least two places (build path for debug and build path for release).

So I thought about using the `#If DEBUG Then` directive to get the xml file from another place when in debug mode.

Is there a way to figure out the solution path at runtime in debug mode? That's where the master to the xml file is currently saved.

I know that I could take the directory my program is running in and go up two or three directories until I reached the solution path, but that only works if you didn't change the build paths to be completely outside the solution folder.

Comment: How about the file path in app.config or web.config?

Comment: That would be kind of hard coded, wouldn't it? Then I could put the hard coded path right in my `#If DEBUG Then` directive.

Comment: No. You can always change the path without any code change or deployment. By putting it in application code, it becomes "hard coded"

Comment: Your users might find a configurable location for the XML file useful too. Or specify the location of the XML file using a command line option..  You can set command line parameters in the Visual Studio project settings.

Comment: Putting it in a config file is hard coded as well (in my case), because I had to change the config file everytime I changed the solution folder. That's the same amount of work as putting it right into code, in fact it's even more work because I had to open yet another file to do the changes.

Comment: It's not for my users since they never will get a program compiled in debug mode.

Comment: Well if it is just for you or developers, don't change the path often. Change file content but not the location. Agree on that. Or keep file in your solution, enable copy to output directory and just use file name. However, I will still say, use config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack using VS EnvDTE.DTE .

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

You have to replace "**VisualStudio.DTE.15.0**" with your VS version.